# Unable to find DartDev snapshot

Tags: flutter-dependencies

I am having a problem when trying to run my flutter app on an IOS emulator. I get this error "Unable to find DartDev snapshot". See the image below.Please help XD

[image]

My "flutter doctor" is all green when I run it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed my Avast antivirus and it 100% solved the issue. It was blocking the directory from accessing the files.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution -

```sh
    cd [path, where your flutter unzip, is located]/flutter/bin 
    rm -rf cache/
    navigate back to project 
    flutter clean
    flutter run
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I removed the antivirus and its 100% now.